# Failed to resolve any signing credential in Okta Saml2 Single Logout configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, saml-2.0, okta, single-logout

I have the following configuration in my application.yaml file:

```
security:
  saml2:
    relyingparty:
      registration:
        okta:
          signing:
            credentials:
              certificate-location: "classpath:saml/okta.crt"
          assertingparty:
            entity-id: http://www.okta.com/my-entity-id
            verification.credentials:
              - certificate-location: "classpath:saml/okta.crt"
            singlesignon.url: https://url-to-single-sign-on
            singlesignon.sign0request: false
            singlelogout.url: http://url-to-single-logout
```

Now when I have made a form button that POSTs to `/logout`, I am getting the following error:
org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.authentication.logout.OpenSamlSigningUtils.resolveSigningParameters: Failed to resolve any signing credential.

As you can see, I have the credentials mentioned clearly in the yaml config file. I am not able to understand why it is failed with this error. I am new to Okta SAML and I could not find any clear documentation on how to implement Single logout in Okta with examples.

Comment: You need ot create your own private key and public cert and add it to the relying party signing parameter. 
 .signingX509Credentials((signing) -> signing.add(credential)) 

Check out:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/saml2/logout.html